# EF Fluent Many to many relationship with "static" value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I have the below database setup for which I want to setup 2 navigational properties from ItemEntity to it's existing CategoryLineEntities.

For example a navigational property called "Category1Lines" which would lead to all lines in the CategoryLinesEntity-table having CategoryId1 match CategoryId **and** Type being 1.

And a second navigational property called "Category2Lines" which would lead to all lines in the CategoryLinesEntity-table having CategoryId2 match CategoryId **and** Type being 2.

```
public class ItemEntity {
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public string CategoryId1 { get; set; }
 public string CategoryId2 { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryLinesEntity {
 public string CategoryId { get; set; }
 public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible? How would one configure this using Entity Framework 7 and Fluent.

Tried my best understanding "UsingEntity" for Fluent but couldn't get it to work. Alternative would be go the long way and simplify the database model.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. Even in MS SQL you need to have 2 computed (preferably persisted) properties that have static values and then you can create a foreign key relationship by using these properties and the `CategoryId` fields

Comment: I would not understand this class design. Why should there be CategoryId1 and CategoryId2. So even if this can be realised i would not recommend it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/mapping-attributes#inversepropertyattribute Though I personally use the fluent api to explicitly name each navigation property and foreign key. If you really want to filter based on `.Type` you'll need a type hierarchy and discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

The classes you provided does not give enough understanding to me where is 'many-to-many' relationship in this case, but code snippet below might help (it describes one-to-many). I created two classes to be mapped to the same table and invoked HasQueryFilter on both of them to map to different types. Tested with in memory database only.

[image: watch window]

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();

ctx.ItemEntity.Add(new ItemEntity()
{
    Id = "ItemEntityId1"
});

ctx.CategoryLinesEntityType1.Add(new CategoryLinesEntityType1()
{
    CategoryId = "ID1",
    Type = "1",
    ItemEntityId = "ItemEntityId1",
});

ctx.CategoryLinesEntityType2.Add(new CategoryLinesEntityType2()
{
    CategoryId = "ID2",
    Type = "2",
    ItemEntityId = "ItemEntityId1",
});

ctx.SaveChanges();

var itemEntityFromDb = ctx.ItemEntity.First();

class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ItemEntity> ItemEntity { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CategoryLinesEntityType1> CategoryLinesEntityType1 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CategoryLinesEntityType2> CategoryLinesEntityType2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("db");

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryLinesEntityType1>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Type == "1");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryLinesEntityType2>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Type == "2");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
[Table("ItemEntity")]
public class ItemEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryLinesEntityType1> Type1Entities { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryLinesEntityType2> Type2Entities { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryLinesEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemEntity))]
    public string ItemEntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemEntityId))]
    public ItemEntity ItemEntity { get; set; }
}

[Table("CategoryLinesEntity")]
public class CategoryLinesEntityType1 : CategoryLinesEntity
{
}

[Table("CategoryLinesEntity")]
public class CategoryLinesEntityType2 : CategoryLinesEntity
{
}
```